# Why globalization encoding is not working(cannot encode the character set)?

Tags: asp.net, unicode, character-encoding

The character set for my language is **x-iscii-be**. The numbers are like the following in this set:

```
1 -> ১ 
2 -> ২
3 -> ৩
4 -> ৪
5 -> ৫
6 -> ৬
7 -> ৭
8 -> ৮
9 -> ৯
0 -> ০
```

But when the input is given Ι can see in debugger modε nothing is received in the controller parameter (the parameter receives 0, not null value).
I modify the applications globalization class in `web.config` file.

```
<system.web>
<globalization requestEncoding="x-iscii-be" responseEncoding="x-iscii-be" />  
<authentication mode="None" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
```

What should I need to do to correctly encode the number values in my desired character set?

Comment: Can you open the dev tools in the browser and see what data is actually posted. Could it be that the browser does not send the typed input correctly. The input textbox what type does it have? `type="text"` or `"type="number"`?

Comment: It happens for double and int both value but can receive those characters as string type.